# Difference between Frequentist and Bayesian approach to Statistics

Tags: probability, bayesian

What is the difference between the Frequentist vs. the Bayesian approach to Statistics?

Would someone be so kind to come up with a simple example that shows how the approaches and possibly the results differ.

Comment: From Stats.SE: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22/bayesian-and-frequentist-reasoning-in-plain-english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the German tank problem. It is a really interesting problem and [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) provides both forms of analysis

Comment: much apprechiated!